# Possible To Have % Based Element Size, But Have Maximum PX Width It Will Goto?

Tags: html, css

I'm designing a mobile website and I want the image that I am using to be fluid in order to match the individual's browser size. However, I don't want someone to come to the website with a massive browser resolution or something just out of my next media query and have it look bad. So I'm wondering if it's possible to have a maximum width the image will go? For example, if I set the image to 90% width, but then it can say something like, however, it can only be a maximum of 500px long, after that it will just say 500px long. (I also want to do this with other elements, like div wrappers)

Also, with the %'s, does the image maintain it's same aspect ratio?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct behaviour of `max-width` should override the image's `width`. Like so:

```
img {
    width: 90%;
    max-width: 500px;
}
```

MDN page: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/max-width#Notes